# WordPress Polylang Pro translate slugs in English

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I'm using Polylang Pro. I have a page with two languages, Dutch and English. I’m trying to translate the slugs of my English pages, which I have set in the Translations page under Languages. Under Display and Menu’s I have created two menu’s.

When I switch to the English page, my entire menu does show the English page names, but still shows the Dutch slugs. How do I get this to convert to English as well?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, I had to filter the menu items to English and re-add the items.